# Thingsboard data store in kv_ts table

Tags: database, postgresql, thingsboard

i use thingsboard with a PostgreSQL database. I have create a device which is connect with a rule change to get the data and then i visualize this data to the dashboard. I have notice that the data are stored in the table ts_kv. This table have some columns like entity_id , key , ts , etc. So , what is key? How that key is generated? Is this key has relationship with the device data? How can i find which key is represent each data?
I need this information because i need to interact with other system that will pull data from database , so i need to know the data key.

Can i make a different table for  each different device and connect to the dashboard to visualize the data or only the ts_kv table are used?
Is there an analytic documentation about this topics?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't touch TB DB directly if you are new to TB (new == less then 6 months)!!

Please specify which version of TB are you using (CE or PE).

Second, do you know that TB offers vast amount of APIs via which you can do almost anything in the system. List of all APIs should be available on https://<<your domain>>/swagger-ui/.

Third, did you get yourself familiar with the structure of the TB? Things like Devices, Device Groups, Assets, Assets Group, Entity Views, Relations, Customers and Customers groups? You should be able to organize your data so that it's easy to get it out.

Answer (score 0):

- The field *entity_id* is auto-created by ThingsBoard and stores the assigned entity like Device or Asset
- *key* is the name of the telemetry or attribute e.g. temperature or humidity
- *ts* is the timestamp of the datapoint e.g. when it was measured or entered

Therefore you don't need to have separate tables for all your devices. This works all out-of-the-box. In order to select devices in dashboards you have to use entity aliases:
https://thingsboard.io/docs/getting-started-guides/helloworld-pe/#step-32-add-entity-alias

If you have to lookup the entity-ids you could also join the table with the device and/or asset table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but Ιn my ts_kv table the key value is number not a string , so it is not write the  attribute , it has just a number...so how to find the correspondences between number and attribute for each  telemetry data , to be able to distinguish them? For example . In the table ts_kv i recognize the device by entity_id , but how to know which entry is for temperature and which is for humidity?  For the temperature entries it has the number 18 and for humidity has the number 58 (I understood this after observing the data) . If i have many entries data, how to recognize?Thanks.

Comment: There is a second table "ts_kv_dictionary" which contains the mapping from key ID to key name

Comment: Yes that is correct many thanks. I did not find any documentation about it , thingsboard need improvement in the documentation section.